# time-series in python: how to add back trend and seasonal components to arima predictions?

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels

I have applied seasonal decomposition to a time series using `seasonal_decompose`:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import pandas_datareader as data
df = data.get_data_yahoo('UGA', start=everSince, end=today)
df_close = df[['Close']]
result = seasonal_decompose(df_close.resample('1D').asfreq().interpolate(), model='additive')
```

and on the `resid` component, I've trained an ARIMA model that I use for prediction. My question is how to add back the trend and seasonal components to the model prediction?

the model I've trained is an `auto_arima` from the library `pmdarima.arima`.